# Server DNS not resolving on CentOS 6

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, ssh, centos6, nameserver

i have CentOS 6 installed on VPS, where i have installed BIND and setup additional IP on VPS as well for nameservers

as ns1.domain.com and ns2.domain.com

i am unable to get the same resolved to properly work..

some troubleshoots i have done results are as follows:

```
[root@domain ~]# service named restart
Stopping named: .                                          [  OK  ]
Starting named:                                            [  OK  ]
[root@domain ~]# netstar -tcp
-bash: netstar: command not found
[root@domain ~]# service named status
version: 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6_8.3
CPUs found: 2
worker threads: 2
number of zones: 16
debug level: 0
xfers running: 0
xfers deferred: 0
soa queries in progress: 0
query logging is OFF
recursive clients: 0/0/1000
tcp clients: 0/100
server is up and running
named (pid  7488) is running...
[root@domain ~]# rndc status
version: 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.47.rc1.el6_8.3
CPUs found: 2
worker threads: 2
number of zones: 16
debug level: 0
xfers running: 0
xfers deferred: 0
soa queries in progress: 0
query logging is OFF
recursive clients: 0/0/1000
tcp clients: 0/100
server is up and running
```

Problem solved i have used alternate solution for this problem. Thanks for help.

Comment: Maybe you have a firewall running on your host? From the outside indeed your server doesn't seem to work as a DNS server. At what IP is your DNS server listening? Can you post the output of this commands?: 1 - `sudo netstat -aetnpu | grep named`; 2 - `sudo iptables -nvL`

Comment: @Fredi i have added new results as requested by you, can you assist me further on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed you have iptables setup to block everything except connections to ssh and ftp (ports 22 and 21 tcp).

You'll have to allow access to your port 53 in UDP and TCP for your DNS server to be reachable from outside (obviously you can limit who can connect based on your needs). Try this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m udp -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

After that your DNS server should be accessible from the outside, try from your client to resolve something, for example:

```
host google.com xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

In case this configuration is ok, you can save the firewall rules with this:

```
service iptables save
```